# How to use getBounds() in OpenLayers 3

Tags: leaflet, openlayers

I am working on a project to create map using OpenLayers 3. Previously I was working with Leaflet but now I am working with OpenLayers 3.

In Leaflet, I was fetching bounds using below code

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var north = bounds.getNorthEast().wrap().lat;
var east = bounds.getNorthEast().wrap().lng;
var south = bounds.getSouthWest().wrap().lat;
var west = bounds.getSouthWest().wrap().lng;
```

Now I want to do the same in OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `bounds` object in Openlayers, instead it uses an extent array:

```
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
var north = ol.extent.getTopRight(extent)[1];
var east = ol.extent.getTopRight(extent)[0];
var south = ol.extent.getBottomLeft(extent)[1];
var west = ol.extent.getBottomLeft(extent)[0];
```

which gives the same result as

```
var north = extent[3];
var east = extent[2];
var south = extent[1];
var west = extent[0];
```

Additionally OpenLayers uses view projection cooordinates so if you need Lon Lat values you may need to transform the extent:

```
extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, map.getView().getProjection(), 'EPSG:4326');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to see if it works.